# Unable to restore job - apscheduler, sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I'm trying to write my own little python flask app to monitor the hard drives of my server.

But since now, I'm getting trouble using the sqljobstore of apscheduler.
While the server is running, everything is fine. But after a restart, I can't access the web interface and getting the folowing output:

```
Unable to restore job "refresh_disks" -- removing it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 289, in ref_to_obj
    obj = getattr(obj, name)
AttributeError: module 'dirkules.tasks' has no attribute 'refresh_disks'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 141, in _get_jobs
    jobs.append(self._reconstitute_job(row.job_state))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/apscheduler/jobstores/sqlalchemy.py", line 128, in _reconstitute_job
    job.__setstate__(job_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 272, in __setstate__
    self.func = ref_to_obj(self.func_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 292, in ref_to_obj
    raise LookupError('Error resolving reference %s: error looking up object' % ref)
LookupError: Error resolving reference dirkules.tasks:refresh_disks: error looking up object
[2019-04-26 15:46:39 +0200] [13296] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Here is my config.py:

```
import os
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore
#from apscheduler.jobstores.memory import MemoryJobStore

baseDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(baseDir, 'dirkules.db')
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

# The SCHEDULER_JOB_DEFAULTS configuration is per job, that means each job can execute at most 3 threads at the same time.
# The SCHEDULER_EXECUTORS is a global configuration, in this case, only 1 thread will be used for all the jobs.
# I believe the best way for you is to use max_workers: 1 when running locally

SCHEDULER_JOBSTORES = {'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///' + os.path.join(baseDir, 'dirkules.db'))}
#SCHEDULER_JOBSTORES = {'default': MemoryJobStore()}

SCHEDULER_EXECUTORS = {'default': {'type': 'threadpool', 'max_workers': 3}}

SCHEDULER_JOB_DEFAULTS = {'coalesce': False, 'max_instances': 1}

SCHEDULER_API_ENABLED = True
```

init.py:

```
import dirkules.config as config

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

import dirkules.models
db.create_all()
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.start()


#@app.before_first_request
from dirkules import tasks


# from dirkules.models import Time
# from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import NoResultFound
#
# try:
#     Time.query.one()
# except NoResultFound:
#     db.session.add(Time("Drives"))
#     db.session.commit()

import dirkules.views
```

and tasks.py:

```
from dirkules import scheduler
import datetime
import dirkules.driveManagement.driveController as drico

@scheduler.task('interval', id='refresh_disks', seconds=10)
def refresh_disks():
    #drives = drico.getAllDrives()
    print("Drives refreshed")
```

Hopefully, you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Starting the scheduler as a side-effect of importing the module is considered bad practice and is also the likely reason why the attribute lookup fails. I would have to see a simplified, more complete example that reproduces the problem to be sure, however.

Comment: Depends on how the application is structured, but I would advise starting it as part of your application's entry point (like if you have a `__main__` block somewhere).